# Window.location.reload() in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I often use `window.location.reload` on my React Web project.

`window.location.reload();`

Is there any similar way to reload page(component) in react-native?

Comment: When you need to reload the page? for example "goback to same page like i'm asking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you mention is a browser feature. React Native uses native capabilities to render your app, so there are no browser features like `window.location.reload()`

So I am not sure what is your particular use-case for this. I guess it is needed to reload the current screen, not the full app.

In this case, you should use a react-way to re-render your screens. In React the views are re-rendered when the props or state changes. So if you want to trigger a full reload, you need to have some internal state that will trigger a reload. For example, you can use `key` property and a container with an internal state that toggles this key.
But I would consider it a hack. You should really use the react data-driven views
You can read more about key prop either in official docs or check out this article from Google: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/understanding-reacts-key-prop/

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Container = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = React.useState(0);
  const reload = React.useCallback(() => setKey((prevKey) => prevKey + 1), []);
  return <Child reload={reload} key={key} />;
}

const Child = ({ reload }) => {
  const getRandomId = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10);
  // We use useRef to showcase that the view is fully re-rendered. Use ref is initialized once per lifecycle of the React component
  const id = React.useRef(getRandomId());
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>My random id is {id}</Text>
      <Button onPress={reload} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Coding is Life

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={() => this.goBackReload()}/>
```

This is the way to reload the page, ie. when you go back to page you got the call back method. Using this method clear all state value and refresh the page. Another way is refresh control using to reload the app.

```
<ScrollView refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh} />
    }>
</ScrollView>
```

**When you scroll down the screen onRefresh method trigger.**