# Window.location.reload(true) in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i implement window.location.reload(true) in a react native app just like in react web.
I have tried Firebase database triggers like child_added and value but seem not to work.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533860/window-location-reload-in-react-native but doesnt looks like there is a right answer marked in the question.

Comment: The solutions to the link dont seem to reload from the server. ie lack the "true" argument